# How can I get the google pubsub compress data size?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform

```
Publisher publisher = Publisher.newBuilder(topicName)
                    .**setEnableCompression(true)
                    .setCompressionBytesThreshold(100000L)**
                    .build();

ByteString data = ByteString.copyFromUtf8(aBigMessage);
                        PubsubMessage pubsubMessage = PubsubMessage.newBuilder()
                                .setData(data)
                                .build();
ApiFuture<String> messageIdFuture = publisher.publish(pubsubMessage);
```

How can I get the pubsubMessage compressed size before send publish?

Comment: Hi @user2930137, Can you try this [code](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/samples/pubsub-publisher-with-compression#code-sample) to Publish messages with compression rate?

Comment: @PrajnaRaiT I wanted to know how to know what is the message compressed size. I currently know how to compress by google but I need the compress size in order to other validations.